# Using Angular Material to put FAB on seam

Tags: javascript, css, angular-material, presentation

So was looking at googles layout principle, and it seems like they are big on placing buttons on the seam (link below to their documentation)

https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#principles-floating-action-button

There is also a Material Floating Action button 
https://github.com/nobitagit/ng-material-floating-button

But neither one seems to address how to actually place the button there. 
I guess I could hack some CSS or write a javascript function that would do the same thing, but it feels like (to me) that there should be a method for this, to ensure a certain level of consistency. Might be that I am missing something rather obvious, so I thought I would ask:)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this may not be the worlds SMOOTHEST solution, but it works, and that must count for something :)

I Just added a span to md-toolbar with the class "onseam"

```
      <md-toolbar id="toolbar" class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <img layout="row" layout-align="center center" src="/images/logos/logo_strap_white_small.png" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"/>
        <span flex></span>
        <span class="onseam">
<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" style=" position: relative; bottom: -25px;">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" >
          <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        </span>
      </md-toolbar>
```

CSS:

```
.onseam {
  position: relative; 
  bottom: -25px;
}
```

And while it may not be the wrolds best solution, it does work.